# jquery selector not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following code on the page and it works in FF but not IE. I do not have any access to change this line of html code (like adding an id to better target). Could it be that it doesn't work cause there is no DOC type declared?

```
<td align="LEFT"  width="12%" bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><b>Code</b></td>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('td[width="12%"][align="LEFT"] b').hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try using a lower-case `12`?

Comment: Nick, once again you got it right. Funny thing is when you do a source list in IE it is uppercase. So it lists it in uppercase but expects lower case. Makes no sense, Microsoft, oh god. I have another IE specific code issue but I will post another ?. Perhaps you will be around :) If you post an answer I will mark it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was kidding with the above `12` comment, but the issue with IE is indeed the attribute casing, and it *is* case sensitive, make sure your `left` is lower-case (if possible render it in the source this way to begin with) then your check should be:

```
$(function(){
  $('td[width="12%"][align="left"] b').hide();
});
```

---

As an aside, consider using CSS classes for things like this:

```
<td class="code">
```

Then in your stylesheet:

```
.code { text-align: left;, width: 12%; }
```

Then in jQuery you can just use:

```
$('td.code b').hide();
```

Much cleaner all around, and a lighter page for the client.

Comment: Believe me I wish I had access to the html to put a class in it but unfortunately I do not.

Comment: @user357034 - I kinda figured that was the case, hopefully it'll help someone else finding this later who *does* have the option :)

Answer (score 2):

try changing the case of the text thus:

```
$('td[width="12%"][align="left"] b').hide();
```

see in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/mschultheiss/Xjwv7/